# html 5 canvas geometry radius dimensions?

Tags: html, canvas

[image: frame radius]

The outer radius does not follow the inner radius. I am currently using x = width/4 + radius + outset, y = height/4 + radius + outset. I think the outset needs to be some ratio of the hypotenuse.

```
 ctx.arc( width/4 + radius + outset , height/4 + radius + outset , radius, 0, Math.PI/2 );
```

Comment: I don't quite get, what you are trying to draw...

Comment: I am trying to make the outer rectangle follow the inner rectangle so that the dimension does not increase around the corners.

Comment: You need to have the same center point for the rounded corners. Thus if the inner box (100 by 100) has a radius of 20 for the rounded corners then the outer box (120 by 120) is 10 pixels larger on the sides so you just add the 10 pixels to the radius of the outer rounded corners to get 30. Just imagine you are drawing circles around the same center point for the inner and outer arcs for each corner.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. I was adding the outset to the radius origin rather than to the radius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach to the one given in comments, is to stroke the arc using `lineWidth` instead of calculating two rounded rectangles and then fill it.

### Example

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d"),
    radius = 50,
    width = 20;

ctx.lineWidth = width;
ctx.moveTo(0, 20);
ctx.arc(100, 20 + radius, radius, -Math.PI * 0.5, 0);  // upper right corner
ctx.arc(100, 40 + radius, radius, 0, Math.PI * 0.5);   // bottom right corner
// etc...
ctx.strokeStyle = "#EA4885";
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```